# Jasmine can't trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tdd, bdd, jasmine

I am trying to implement a simple Jasmine test in which Jasmine will test if some code is run on click of a input button. But I can't figure why the click is not triggering? I realize it will if i just have the `.click()` function in beforeEach but I don't think that's how it's suppose to work.

**specs**

```
describe("export citations", function (){
  var btn
  beforeEach(function(){            
    btn= $("input#myButton").eq(0);
  });

  it("should call click function", function() {
    btn.trigger("click");
    expect($("#content").length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

**fixture**

```
$(function(){
  $("input#myButton").click(function(e){
  //Run a bunch of code here
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you actually added an element to the DOM in the fixture? Also you are missing a ); in the fixture to close the click callback.

This worked for me:

```
describe("export citations", function () {
  var btn;
  beforeEach(function() {
    btn= $("input#myButton").eq(0);
  });

  it("should call click function", function() {
    btn.click();
    expect($("#content").length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

fixture

```
(function() {
  $("body").html("<input id='myButton' type='button'>");

  $("body").html("<div id='content'></div>");

  $("input#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#content").html("<p>Hello</p>");
  });
})();
```

Comment: How/where do you load your fixture?

Comment: A long time since I've worked on this, but I think this describes it: http://testdrivenwebsites.com/2010/07/29/html-fixtures-in-jasmine-using-jasmine-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I think your fixture should be like this to suit your Test Case

```
    (function() {
        $("body").html("<input id='myButton' type='button'>");

        $("input#myButton").click(function() {
            $("body").append("<div id='content'>")
        });
    })();
```